# Below code is giving error : Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Child1' to 'Test<bool, object>'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

The blow code is not running giving the error: "Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Child1' to 'Test<bool, object>'", I am creating the abstract class, which takes the Same abstract class as a parameter in the constructor. and After creating the child class of them and passing another child class as a parameter to one's constructor giving compilation error as mentioned.
Tried ChatGPT it says logically code is correct, but why visual studio code is giving compile time error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1379331/compilation-error-cs8625-c

```
abstract class Test<A, B>
{
    private Test<B, object> t1;

    public Test(Test<B, object> t)
    {
        t1 = t;
    }
}

class Child1 : Test<int, string>
{
    public Child1(Test<string, object> t) : base(t)
    {
    }
}

class Child2 : Test<string, bool>
{
    public Child2(Test<bool, object> t) : base(t)
    {
    }
}

class Main
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Child2 c2 = new Child2(null);
        Child1 c1 = new Child1(c2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have test in my local and share the test result to you, happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce the code in my local like below.

[image]

**Here is the working sample, it can help you fix it.**

```
namespace CS1503
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Child2 c2 = new Child2(null); 
            Child1 c1 = new Child1(c2);
        }
    }
    interface ITest<out A, out B>
    {
        // Covariant interface with no members that use A or B in input positions.
    }

    abstract class Test<A, B> : ITest<A, B>
    {
        private ITest<B, object> t1;

        protected Test(ITest<B, object> t)
        {
            t1 = t;
        }

        // Additional functionality for the Test class could be added here.
    }

    class Child1 : Test<int, string>
    {
        public Child1(ITest<string, object> t) : base(t)
        {
        }

        // Additional functionality for the Child1 class could be added here.
    }

    class Child2 : Test<string, bool>, ITest<string, object> // Explicitly implementing the needed interface
    {
        public Child2(ITest<bool, object> t) : base(t)
        {
        }

        // Additional functionality for the Child2 class could be added here.
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: @JsonPan if I wanted to return it like below: class Main
{
    public Test<int,object> definedTest() {

        Child3 c3 = new Child3(null);
        Child2 c2 = new Child2(c3);
        Child1 c1 = new Child1(c2);
         return c1;
       }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.definedTest();
        

    }
}  It gives the same error, again.

Comment: @Json Pan Thanks for your response, I missed in my previous comments.

Comment: Yes it does, Thanks for the solution!!

Answer (score 1):

That error looks right to me.

- `t1` is a `Child1`, which is a `Test<string, string>`.
- `t2` is a `Child2`.
- `Child2`'s constructor takes a `Test<bool, object>`
- `t1` cannot be converted from a `Test<string, string>` to a `Test<bool, object>` because its specified class-types don't match. Simply, a `string` is not a `bool`.

Maybe, you want the `Child1` and `Child2` sub-classes to be generic too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry there was a small update. I have updated the code. I hope now it makes more sense. Ca you please help me now? I am getting the same error as I mentioned.

Comment: I am now getting an error about `Child2`, rather than `Child1`. But the explanation still applies:  `Test<string, bool>` is not the same as `Test<string, object>`

Comment: I ran the same code in Java and it worked fine, I am new to c#, converted to C# giving me a compilation error.